# What is the structure of Qiskit's amplitude-encoded quantum circuit?

Tags: qiskit, encoding

A problem that has been ignored before is that Ansatz does not know that classical data becomes quantum data. Although Qiskit provides the Initialize() function that can be initialized directly.

I'm curious why a circuit that initializes an arbitrary quantum state is the way it is.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This circuit is very similar to https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0407010, which is the [MottonenStatePreparation](https://docs.pennylane.ai/en/stable/code/api/pennylane.MottonenStatePreparation.html) in Pennylane.